# How do I set a Swift dictionary nil value such that my server receives null for the key?

Tags: ios, swift

My server has a requirement that a key be present but the value be `null`. When I set the key to nil on the Swift-side, the key is no longer present in the dictionary. Is there any way to send the key without data such that I don't have to change my server?

Comment: It depends on how you are communicating this dictionary to the server. Is this JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSNull` instead of `nil`.

Example:

```
parameters["foo"] = NSNull()
```

Comment: Never knew that was a thing. Neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript) talk about how using subscript to assign nil will remove the key (at the bottom of the page).

You can use [updateValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127179-updatevalue) to assign a value of nil to a key without removing the key.

```swift
var foo: [String: Int?] = [:]
foo["one"] = 1
foo["two"] = 2
foo["one"] = nil // removes the key "one"
foo.updateValue(nil, forKey: "two") // the key "two" remains, with value nil
```